# Java Threads for Memory Management

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, neo4j

I have an application that performs a very sequential set of discrete tasks.

My problem is that one of the first tasks consumes a large amount of memory, and despite eliminating object references and invoking the garbage collector, only about half the memory is essentially freed. This impacts later tasks. The problem is also that I want to temporarily grant the JVM a large heap to efficiently manage the first task but I don't want this to stick around till the GC decides it's efficient to free the rest.

I had the idea of executing the memory-intensive task inside thread; the new child thread uses the parent JVM (no surprise here), but there appears to be no change in the memory management.

How does Java handle Thread memory? Is there a simple way to create a child heap for the subthread that can be dumped after the thread has finished?

As an addendum, here's what I actually want to do:

1. Setup a Neo4j graph database (I'm creating several million nodes, properties and relationships, along with numerous indexes) [memory intensive]
2. Perform queries on the graph database

Comment: Do you actually run out of memory at any point? If so, increase memory for the VM. If not, don’t bother trying to understand how the VM handles memory. Any attempt to do so will only lead to horrible code that breaks when the VM changes how it handles memory.

Comment: I do run out of memory; I could have increased the JVM memory but I didn't want so much memory to be available to the rest of the code. Also, the point of the proof of concept was to run this with as little as possible. I found out there are very nice ways to configure memory management for neo4j directly (see marked answer below).
I agree with your notion about not bothering to trick with mem management and the GC for practical purposes, but it's still fun to explore the possibilities ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, heap is shared between threads and there isn't a way to reserve memory for a given thread or allow a thread to break limits. Threads are not processes (despite they are implemented this way in some jvm).

You could run this thread in a separate procss (different JVM) and pass data to it via files or sockets, but while it would solve memory problems, it could kill performances ... but depends on how much data you need to pass.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know! Anyone looking for how I solved the problem finally check Arnout's answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use a memory profiler to find out which GC root is keeping the objects alive that you expected to be garbage-collected.

I expect, however, Neo4j is keeping those objects alive and there might be little you can do about it. After all, your graph and its indexes do need to be there for you to be able to perform queries on them.

You might be able to find some Neo4j API call to tell it to clean out some caches or something similar.

Comment: Yes, with Neo4j that's the case; this is how I actually solved my problem by setting
`cache_type = none`
as configuration parameter, telling neo4j to not store any nodes in the heap. It says it's not recommended and I can understand why, but for my purposes (testing) it's very useful. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.
For anyone else looking:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/configuration-caches.html
http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Configuration_Settings

Comment: Regarding cleaning the caches: See the [instructions on reading jmx attributes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-java-embedded-jmx.html) - just use Cache.class instead, and there is a [clear()](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-management/snapshot/apidocs/org/neo4j/management/Cache.html) method in it. Note: this feature only exists in the AGPL-licensed Advanced and Enterprise editions of Neo4j.